# How to find out the file path of a wordpress site in FTP?

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I have the FTP access for my Wordpress site, but i can't find the root folder of my site,but in the admin section, file path of an image in media has http://site1.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/loading-624x832.jpg, I have searched all the folders but not this image is not in any of the files.Any idea or solution to find the path? Thanks for your response in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to your site than put this `echo get_template_directory();` in your theme's `functions.php` file.

After adding that line, Navigate to your site and there top of your site you can see full directory path of your theme.

Now you can locate you WordPress site directory by replacing `wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME_NAME`.

when you know directory path, remove this line so other can not see for security.

This might help you little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the hosting company you use for your website, it could be in many locations e.g. httpdocs, httpdocs, siteapps, public_html, or www, or maybe even something else.

You should contact your hosting company to find out where wordpress is installed from the control panel.

Comment: Thank you,Is there any way to find out from cpanel,because i have the access to cpanel.

Comment: If you check or try to edit the wordpress options under blogs or web applications, you might find the location there.